# Is overloading addition or multiplication operator similar to constructor?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have the following two classes: closePrime() and trigger().

The trigger() class has a dynamically allocated object array of closePrime objects:

```
//trigger.h

#include "closePrime.h"
using namespace std;

class trigger
{
    private:
       closePrime* objArray;
       int size;
       ...

    public:
       trigger();
       trigger(int s);
       ...
}
```

...

```
// trigger.cpp
trigger::trigger()
{
    size = 2;
    objArray = new closePrime[size];
}

trigger::trigger(int s)
{
    size = s;
    objArray = new closePrime[size];
}
```

Is it possible to **overload the addition or multiplication operator** so that **in main/my driver** I can do something along the following lines:

```
int main()
{
    // i'm not sure if this would be the syntax
    trigger triggerObj + 3;

    // or something like
    trigger triggerObj * 3;
}
```

**And it would be equal to saying**

```
int main()
{
    trigger triggerObj(3);
}
```

I am new to operator overloading so **I was wondering if one, both, or neither of these were possible?** I wasn't sure where I would put the code even if it was. Let me know if I need to share more info. Thank you.

Note: No STL

Comment: no, at least not in the form of `trigger triggerObj + 3`

Comment: What would you gain by doing that?

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger triggerObj + 3;
```

Doesn't look like a legal construct within the language (c++).

However you may modify it to something like:

```
trigger triggerObj = trigger() + 3;
```

or

```
trigger triggerObj = whatever + 3;
```

Then overload `+` and possible `=` if needed.